# O HTML não esta sendo exibido

Tags: html, twig

Tenho um campo na minha tabela que grava textos formatados em *HTML* corretamente. Quando estou tentando exibi-lo na tela, via *TWIG* usando o filtro *RAW*, ele continua sendo exibido como texto e não como *HTML*.

Notei que o *TWIG* está colocando uma aspas no início e no final do texto.

Como faço para exibir o *HTML* original?

Estou usando assim: `{{ texto|raw }}`.

E a saída é mais ou menos assim:

```
<span><p>teste</p></span>
```

Se eu peço para ver o código *HTML* da página, está assim:

```
"<span><p>teste</p></span>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi usando o `htmlspecialchars_decode();` antes de enviar para o TWIG.